# Escape all special chars for expect send in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, expect

I need to send some strings with expect to a system via telnet and got following example strings:

```
    $ cat SERVERTEMPPASSWORDLIST.txt
    SID=21|21|asldf8j2sRa2255||2840400|
    SID=21|27|ala"sd8fjs2A"$||2840400|alsd8fj2s%"aa
    SID=21|27|alsd"8fujs!"sl9a2e4|asdf2$sa5$23|2840400|asdfs2asl92
    SID=21|21|holysshit||2840400|
```

The script has to do this:

```
    $ cat test.sh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    (
        grep -E "SID=${sid}" SERVERTEMPPASSWORDLIST.txt | while read line; do
            TCID=$(echo ${line} | cut -d '|' -f 2)
            TSPW="$(echo ${line} | cut -d '|' -f 3)"
            TCPW="$(echo ${line} | cut -d '|' -f 4)"
            DURATION="$(echo ${line} | cut -d '|' -f 5)"
            DESC="$(echo ${line} | cut -d '|' -f 6)"

            if [[ "${TCPW}" != "" ]]; then
                cat <<- ADDENTRY
                    expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
                    send "addentry pw=${TSPW} desc=${DESC} duration=${DURATION} tcid=${TCID} tcpw=${TCPW}\r"
                ADDENTRY
            else
                cat <<- ADDENTRY
                    expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
                    send "addentry pw=${TSPW} desc=${DESC} duration=${DURATION} tcid=${TCID}\r"
                ADDENTRY
            fi
        done
    ) | expect > RESULT.txt
```

Regarding some special chars like " and $ it fails with the error message, that has some extra chars after close-quote or it can't find the variable 'sa5' for example.

```
    $ ./test.sh
    extra characters after close-quote
        while executing
    "send "addentry pw=ala"s"
```

Some text, which I need to send with expect is already escaped, because spaces needs to be send as '\s' instead of ' '. For example would you send

```
    Hello World!
```

as

```
    Hello\sWorld!
```

It's important, that there are no double escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the string into braces:

```
            cat <<- ADDENTRY
                expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
                send {addentry pw=${TSPW} desc=${DESC} duration=${DURATION} tcid=${TCID} tcpw=${TCPW}}
                expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
                send "\r"
            ADDENTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing languages like this will cause you grief. Just use expect. And, what are you spawning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set sid [lindex $argv 0]
set fid [open SERVERTEMPPASSWORDLIST.txt r]

spawn ???

while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    if { ! [string match "*SID=$sid*" $line} continue

    # string replacements
    set line [string map {{ } {\s} {"} {\"}} $line]
    lassign [split $line |] tcid tspw tcpw duration desc

    if {$tcpw ne ""} {
        expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
        send "addentry pw=$tspw desc=$desc duration=$duration tcid=$tcid tcpw=$tcpw\r"
    } else {
        expect "error id=0 msg=ok"
        send "addentry pw=$tspw desc=$desc duration=$duration tcid=$tcid tcpw=$tcpw\r"
    }
}
```

And pass the SID as the first argument to the expect script

Comment: The script contains more than 3100 lines, this is the reason, why I've mixed languages - I need some bash features. The above answer works fine. Anyway thx for your help!

Comment: I'm very curious what features of bash you need that don't exist in Tcl/Expect. Anyway, good luck maintaining that script.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I expressed it a bit wrong. I want to allow the user to choose whether you would use bash or expect.